# variable does not exist in for loop

Tags: javascript, html

This program adds table row `for each` client and inside that `table row`, a `td` for every value of the client (like name, ip, value, etc.).
These values and client are set in a `key/value object` or `dictionary` called `clientel`.

I've set the program as follows:

```js
let clientel = {
  socket101: ['Rick', '192.590.49.1', 'Win10', 'Norway', '15:49.00'],
  socket102: ['Anthony', '192.90.897.0', 'Win7', 'Negritine', '19:19:38']
};

function man_table() {
  const table = document.getElementById('table-body');
  for (let i, client in clientel) {
    let row = table.insertRow(i);
    let index = row.insertCell(0);
    let name = row.insertCell(1);
    let ip = row.insertCell(2);
    let os = row.insertCell(3);
    let country = row.insertCell(4);
    let timee = row.insertCell(5);

    index.innerHTML = i;
    name.innerHTML = client[0];
    ip.innerHTML = client[1];
    os.innerHTML = client[2];
    country.innerHTML = client[3];
    timee.innerHTML = client[4];
  }
};

function roomba() {
  for (let client in clientel) {
    console.log(client)
  }
};
```

I have buttons that executes the functions when I press em' but for some reason it says that `clientel` is not defined?

Comment: Are you sure the error is about `clientel`, not `client`?

Comment: You can't assign two variables in `for-in` statement.

Comment: @Barmar semi-on-topic.. can you destructure the assignment of a `for..in`?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: There's no object or array being assigned, so there's nothing to destructure.

Comment: When I run your code I get a syntax error: **Invalid left-hand side in for-in loop: Must have a single binding.**

Comment: @Barmar I had a feeling you couldn't assign two. Which is why I made the function `roomba` that has only one variable. It too, says that `clientel` is not defined.

Comment: Yea I get that error too. It's all mixed up. I get that error from the `man_table()` and the not defined one from `roomba()`. What's going on?

Comment: `roomba()` doesn't try to assign two variables in the `for-in` loop.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with `clientel`. See my answer, the code works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign `i` and `client` in a `for-in` loop. You need to use `clientel[i]` to get the property value.

```js
let clientel = {
  socket101: ['Rick', '192.590.49.1', 'Win10', 'Norway', '15:49.00'],
  socket102: ['Anthony', '192.90.897.0', 'Win7', 'Negritine', '19:19:38']
};

function man_table() {
  const table = document.getElementById('table-body');
  for (let i in clientel) {
    let row = table.insertRow(i);
    let index = row.insertCell(0);
    let name = row.insertCell(1);
    let ip = row.insertCell(2);
    let os = row.insertCell(3);
    let country = row.insertCell(4);
    let timee = row.insertCell(5);

    let client = clientel[i];
    index.innerHTML = i;
    name.innerHTML = client[0];
    ip.innerHTML = client[1];
    os.innerHTML = client[2];
    country.innerHTML = client[3];
    timee.innerHTML = client[4];
  }
};

function roomba() {
  for (let client in clientel) {
    console.log(client)
  }
};

man_table();
```

```html
<table id="table-body">
</table>
```

Comment: Also, btw, is there a way I can like thread the function `man_table()`? Like it just runs in the background so it automatically adds a client to the table when ever it's added to the `clientel`?

Comment: You could use `setInterval()` to run a function periodically that updates the table from `clientel`.

Comment: But it would probably be better to just put the code that updates `clientel` in a function, and have it call `man_table()` when it's done.